# Not recognizning ENV variables in S3.yml in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, yaml

I'm currently trying to configure Paperclip with newest `aws-sdk` suggested gem.

On my S3.yml file I have something like this

```
development:
  bucket: newmeeter-dev
  access_key_id: ENV['S3_KEY']
  secret_access_key: ENV['S3_SECRET']
```

But it is not recognizing the ENV variables. I'm getting the following error

```
AWS::S3::Errors::InvalidAccessKeyId in PhotosController#create

The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
```

If I try to put both the access and secret directly into the file it works perfectly. At the same time I tried to print both ENV variables into the views or in the console I can see their values okay.

I'm not getting why it is not recognizing it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solved!

I found the reply to this question here 
[Ruby on Rails: Can you put Ruby code in a YAML config file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277428/ruby-on-rails-can-you-put-ruby-code-in-a-yaml-config-file)

Solution: YAML files understand code in ERB format.

Printing ENV variables inside `<%=` and `%>` works.

```
access_key_id: <%= ENV['S3_KEY'] %>
secret_access_key: <%= ENV['S3_SECRET'] %>
```

Comment: Did they recently change this? Looks like `<%= ENV['something'] $>` is evaluating to `"ENV['something']"`.

Comment: @Noz Use this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277428/ruby-on-rails-can-you-put-ruby-code-in-a-yaml-config-file