# DRY up YAML with variables

Tags: yaml

As you can see this isn't very DRY:

```
en:
  dashboard_policy:
    statistics?: 'You cannot access the statistics panel because you are not an admin!content'
    forums?: 'You cannot access the forums panel because you are not an admin!'
    browser?: 'You cannot access the browser panel because you are not an admin!'
    users?: 'You cannot access the users panel because you are not an admin!'
```

It is possible to have methods or variables inside YAML, in order to stop repeating myself?

Comment: possible duplicate of [using YAML with variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150782/using-yaml-with-variables)

Comment: @Senjai It's related, but it's not an exact duplicate.

Comment: Another option: pre-process your YAML with ERB. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/3277428/1301972 for some examples.

Comment: **See also:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15777987/string-interpolation-in-yaml

Answer (score 2):

### Use Anchors and Alias Nodes

You can't use variables within YAML directly, although you can embed them in strings for your *program code* to interpolate. However, you can DRY up YAML a lot using anchors and alias nodes. For example:

```
en:
  warn_not_admin: &warn_not_admin
    "You can't access this panel because you aren't an admin."                        
  dashboard_policy:
    statistics?: *warn_not_admin
    forums?:     *warn_not_admin
    browser?:    *warn_not_admin
    users?:      *warn_not_admin
```

This defines an anchor named *warn_not_admin*, assigns it to the value of the :warn_not_admin key, and then references that node in each child element of the :dashboard_policy key.

Note that in this particular case, we reuse the same message. This adds a little more DRY-ness by assuming that your users know which panel they're dealing with. If they *really* need to be told which panel the message refers to, using interpolation within your code (as described by [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25852762/1301972)) might be a reasonable alternative.

Comment: This ignores the message differences.

Comment: @DaveNewton Yup. If you want interpolation, Lucas has a [reasonable answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25852762/1301972). Personally, I'd rather see the message changed to "You can't access this panel because you aren't an admin." and keep it really DRY. YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use variables in yml other than reusing whole value or passing variables to tranlations by using `%{variable}` notation.

So in your case I would write something like:

```
en:
  dashboard_policy:
    access_denied: 'You cannot access the %{location} because you are not an admin!'
  locations:
    forums: "forums panel"
    ...
```

Then in your view i.e.:

```
<%= t('dashboard_policy.access_denied', location: t('locations.forums')) %>
```

Comment: This is a reasonable answer, but the interpolation then happens in the code, not in the YAML. It's a distinction worth noting; you *did* note it, but I'm just clarifying it a little for future visitors.